# White Pixel artifacts when using drawImage in QPainter Pyside

Tags: pyside, scaling, drawimage, qpainter, artifacts

I'm painting an image in a QPainter object with:

```
QPainterObject.drawImage(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0), image)
```

The image itself is huge, (12.000 x 25.000 pixels).

When I scale the picture near it's "original" scale everything is fine, but when I reduce its size, white pixels start appearing all over the image. 
I understand it's an interpolation problem and I've tried setting up the
render hints:

```
        QPainterobject.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing,QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
```

But it makes no difference in the end result.

Is there another way to render better the scaled image?
The scaling algorithm is doing probably nearest neighbour approach but I want interpolation.